# Windows forms setup wizard is not copying the 'copy always' files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation, setup-wizard

I created a Setup Wizard project for my Windows forms application and created an installer. There are some files that I have marked as 'Copy always' but they dont show in the folder created from the installer. [How i set the file to copy always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcrSh.png)

Comment: I have tested it in by publishing installer, but I can not reproduce your problem. I can see the file in the folder created from the installer.

Comment: It worked by setting the buildaction of the files to content and include content of project when setting up the setup wizard